# pipeline for RandomOversampler, RandomForestClassifier & GridSearchCV

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest, gridsearchcv, imblearn

I am working on a binary text classification problem. As the classes are highly imbalanced, I am using sampling techniques like `RandomOversampler()`. Then for classification I would use `RandomForestClassifier()` whose parameters need to be tuned using `GridSearchCV()`.

I am trying to create a pipeline to do these in order but failed so far. It throws `invalid parameters`.

```
param_grid = {
             'n_estimators': [5, 10, 15, 20],
             'max_depth': [2, 5, 7, 9]
         }
grid_pipe = make_pipeline(RandomOverSampler(),RandomForestClassifier())
grid_searcher = GridSearchCV(grid_pipe,param_grid,cv=10)
grid_searcher.fit(tfidf_train[predictors],tfidf_train[target])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parameters you defined in the `params` is for RandomForestClassifier, but in the gridSearchCV, you are not passing a `RandomForestClassifier` object.

You are passing a pipeline object, for which you have to rename the parameters to access the internal RandomForestClassifier object.

Change them to:

```
param_grid = {
             'randomforestclassifier__n_estimators': [5, 10, 15, 20],
             'randomforestclassifier__max_depth': [2, 5, 7, 9]
             }
```

And it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for A2A. Ideally the parameters are defined as follows:

1. Create a pipeline for the transformers to be applied on the data

> `pipeline = make_pipeline([('variable initialization
>   1',transformers1()),('variable initialization 2',transformers2()),]`

Note: Do not forget to end the pipeline with a ',' before closing off square brackets

> `eg:pipeline =
>   make_pipeline([('random_over_sampler',RandomOverSampler()),('RandomForestClassifier',
>   RandomForestClassifier()),]`

2. Create a parameter grid

> ```
> param_grid = {'transformations/algorithm'__'parameter_in_transformations/algorithm':[parameters]}
>
> eg: param_grid = {RandomOverSampler__sampling_strategy:['auto']}
> ```